# PHP image resize black background - change colour

Tags: php, image, resize

So I am using this code to resize an image on the fly and create a copy of it.

```
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
```

But what I don't like is it gives a default **black** background. How could I change this **black** background to something like, **white**?

Here it is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you initialize `$tci`, you can use [`imagefill()`](http://php.net/imagefill) and [`imagecolorallocate()`](http://php.net/imagecolorallocate) to fill the image with white:

```
$white = imagecolorallocate($tci, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($tci, 0, 0, $white);
```

Note:  this will only work if the source image uses transparent pixels.